# Justification when using the dramatist package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, dramatist

I'm trying to typset a play using the [`dramatist`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dramatist) package. I'm having difficulty figuring out how I change some settings. I want to ensure that the text that the characters say, is justified, rather than their names being justified.

[image]

I would like the words `Well`, `Start` and `I` to be left-justified, and the characters names to be right-justified. Here is an example of the `tex` that I used to make this demo:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{memoir}    
\usepackage{dramatist}  

\begin{document}

\Character[Wilheim - a person]{Wilheim}{will} % define characters
\Character[Frederico - a person]{Frederico}{fred}

\scene[]

\StageDir{
    \begin{center} Darkness
     \end{center}
}

\begin{drama}

\willspeaks Well, will we - I\dots
\fredspeaks  Start.
\willspeaks I will go on.
\willspeaks Vivamus varius tellus et mi pretium elementum iaculis tellus semper. Donec semper iaculis ante, convallis convallis arcu laoreet vitae. Aliquam id leo ac eros ultrices rhoncus porta sed ipsum. 

\end{drama}

\end{document}
```

I would like my document to look like the following (which I prepared using the `verbatim` package) and for this to work for sentences that run over multiple lines:

[image]

I received some helpful advice from TeX.SE on starting to use the `dramatist` package [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/what-are-good-packages-for-laying-out-a-play).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make some surgery on the internal commands of `dramatist`; the easiest way is to use `etoolbox` and `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{memoir}    
\usepackage{dramatist,etoolbox,enumitem}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{drama}
  {\if@lnpa
   \PackageWarning{dramatist}{\lnpwarning{a}}
   \fi
   \if@lnps
   \PackageWarning{dramatist}{\lnpwarning{s}}
   \fi
   \begin{itemize}[labelwidth=\speakswidth,leftmargin=!]} 
  {\end{itemize}}
\patchcmd{\speaker}{\item[#1\speaksdel]}{\item[\speaksfont#1]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@character}{\item[#1\speaksdel]}{\item[\speaksfont#1]}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\Character[Wilheim - a person]{Wilheim}{will} % define characters
\Character[Frederico - a person]{Frederico}{fred}
\settowidth{\speakswidth}{\speaksfont{Frederico}\speaksdel\hspace{\speechskip}}


\scene[]

\StageDir{
    \begin{center} Darkness
     \end{center}
}

\begin{drama}

\willspeaks Vivamus varius tellus et mi pretium elementum iaculis tellus semper. Donec semper iaculis ante, 
convallis convallis arcu laoreet vitae. Aliquam id leo ac eros ultrices rhoncus porta sed ipsum.

\fredspeaks Vivamus varius tellus et mi pretium elementum iaculis tellus semper. Donec semper iaculis ante, 
convallis convallis arcu laoreet vitae. Aliquam id leo ac eros ultrices rhoncus porta sed ipsum.
\willspeaks Vivamus varius tellus et mi pretium elementum iaculis tellus semper. Donec semper iaculis ante, 
convallis convallis arcu laoreet vitae. Aliquam id leo ac eros ultrices rhoncus porta sed ipsum.

\end{drama}

\end{document}
```

The setting of `\speakswidth` is best done after all characters are introduced, so that one can choose the widest one.
[image]

Comment: perfect! Thank you. I chose to edit the line `\begin{itemize}[labelwidth=25pt,leftmargin=20pt]}` and manually inserted the values which I found easier.

Comment: I have a problem with this answer. It causes the stage directions in the drama environment to be centered with the dialogue (right column) and not the page. Is there a way to modify this answer to make the stage directions center on the page?

Comment: @Darling Do you mean "Darkness"? Its position is independent of the patch.

Comment: @egreg I mean if you use \StageDir{\begin{center}Some text.\end{center}} within a drama environment it is no longer centreed on the page. I have some stage directions in a drama environment and some outside and it is looking messy.

Comment: @Darling It would be better to make a follow-up question

Comment: @egreg follow up created http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45322/problem-with-the-allignment-of-stage-directions-when-using-dramatist

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: I missed the detail about right-justification. But aside from that

---

`\speakswidth` and `\speaksindent` are the critical parts here (section 2.2 of the dramatist documentation).

Easy version, adding an arbitrary amount of space that allows the speaker labels to fit:

```
\setlength{\speakswidth}{1in}
\setlength{\speaksindent}{0.5in}
```

More complicated version which uses the [calc](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) package to automatically calculate the required space, and keeps the other margins and lengths consistent. Use the longest character name in your script on `\setlength` line below:

```
\setlength{\speakswidth}{\widthof{\speaksfont Frederico}}
\addtolength{\speakswidth}{\Dlabelsep}
\addtolength{\speaksindent}{\speakswidth}
```

Full version:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{memoir}    
\usepackage{dramatist}  
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\Character[Wilheim - a person]{Wilheim}{will}
\Character[Frederico - a person]{Frederico}{fred}
\setlength{\speakswidth}{\widthof{\speaksfont Frederico}}
\addtolength{\speakswidth}{\Dlabelsep}
\addtolength{\speaksindent}{\speakswidth}
\scene[]
\StageDir{
    \begin{center} Darkness
     \end{center}
}
\begin{drama}
\willspeaks Well, will we - I\dots
\fredspeaks  Start.
\willspeaks I will go on.
\end{drama}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mike. Do you know how I would deal with a sentence that runs over multiple lines? For example `\willspeaks Vivamus varius tellus et mi pretium elementum iaculis tellus semper. Donec semper iaculis ante, convallis convallis arcu laoreet vitae. Aliquam id leo ac eros ultrices rhoncus porta sed ipsum.` does not follow the same margin.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake... it works fine when I choose appropriate values.