# Dramatist package putting speaker in different places when mixing prose and verse

Tags: dramatist

I have document that contains both prose and verse. When using the `dramatist` package, the speaker is placed above verse and beside prose. I'd like them to both to the left of the text, similar to the first answer to [Justification when using the dramatist package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39360/justification-when-using-the-dramatist-package).

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}    
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}
\linenumberfrequency{5}

\begin{document}

\Character[Billy Prose]{BILLY}{billy}
\Character[Sally Verse]{SALLY}{sally}

\begin{drama*}

\sallyspeaks I am a poet \\
I know it\\
I like to speak in short lines\\
Like this\\
My cat is gray\\
My fish is dead\\
Because the cat ate it\\
I am\\
A very difficult person\\
To have a conversation with.\
\end{drama*}

\begin{drama}

    \billyspeaks I like to talk like a normal person. Your cat is lame. I have a gerbil named Phil. He sleeps in my dresser. I'm so sorry that my examples sounds insane.

\end{drama}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just use the `drama` environment like you did for Billy?  Or wrap the verse in a minipage
    \begin{drama}

```
\sallyspeaks
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.75\linewidth}
     I am a poet \\
    I know it\\
    I like to speak in short lines\\
    Like this\\
    My cat is gray\\
    My fish is dead\\
    Because the cat ate it\\
    I am\\
    A very difficult person\\
    To have a conversation with.        \end{minipage}

\end{drama}
```

[image]

Apparently you can nest `drama*` inside `drama`.  And looking at the documentation, it seems that it shouldn't be hard to create your own speaker-verse environment.  Here's the result of playing around a bit:

```
\documentclass{memoir}    
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}
\linenumberfrequency{5}
% Make your own nested environment as a work-around
\newenvironment{dramaverse}{\hspace*{\fill}\par\begin{drama*}}
                           {\end{drama*}}
% Define your own version of `drama*` but don't throw the `drversetrue` switch
% Make your own switch.  At most you may have to redefine `\direct` to get
% some possibly desirable effects from there.
\makeatletter
\newif\if@mydrverse
\@namedef{mydrama*}{%
    \@mydrversetrue
    \if@poemscol
        \begin{poem}
        \setcounter{verselinenumber}{\value{storelineno}}
        \setcounter{printlineindex}{\value{storeprintlineindex}}
    \else
        \begin{verse}
    \fi
    \ifx\poemlines\@undefined\else
        \setcounter{poemline}{\value{storelineno}}
    \fi}
\@namedef{endmydrama*}{%
    \ifx\poemlines\@undefined\else
        \setcounter{storelineno}{\value{poemline}}
    \fi
    \if@poemscol
        \end{poem}
        \setcounter{storelineno}{\value{verselinenumber}}
        \setcounter{storeprintlineindex}{\value{printlineindex}}
    \else
        \end{verse}
    \fi
    \@mydrversefalse}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\Character[Billy Prose]{BILLY}{billy}
\Character[George Prose]{GEORGE}{george}
\Character[Sally Verse]{SALLY}{sally}

\verb=drama*= nested in \verb=drama=
\begin{drama}
    \sallyspeaks
        \begin{drama*}
        I am a poet \\
        I know it\\
        I like to speak in short lines\\
        Like this\\
        My cat is gray\\
        My fish is dead\\
        Because the cat ate it\\
        I am\\
        A very difficult person\\
        To have a conversation with.\\
        \end{drama*}
\end{drama}


Using the new \verb=dramaverse= work-around environment nested inside \verb=drama=.
\begin{drama}
    \georgespeaks
    \begin{dramaverse}
    I am not a poet\\
    I know it\\
    I hate talking in verse\\
    Like this\\
    My dog is white\\
    My Lizard is alive\\
    Because my dog didn't eat\\
    It yet\\
    I am easy\\
    To get along with\\
    \end{dramaverse}
\end{drama}

    \begin{drama}
    \sallyspeaks I knew it!
    \end{drama}

\begin{drama}
    \billyspeaks I like to talk like a normal person. Your cat is lame. I
    have a gerbil named Phil. He sleeps in my dresser. I'm so sorry that my
    examples sounds insane.  You are deranged.
\end{drama}

Using the package's own \verb=drama*= environment.
\begin{drama*}
    \sallyspeaks Silly man, you\\
            Deranged is who?
\end{drama*}

Using your new reworked version of \verb=drama*= called \verb=mydrama*=.
But now I get some unexpected vertical whitespace.
\begin{mydrama*}
    \billyspeaks
    Who's making me\\
    Talk so strange.\\
    I can't believe\\
    You think I'm deranged\\
\end{mydrama*}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are features in the drama* environment for verse, such as line numbering, that I don't want to lose out on. Using the drama environment instead of the starred version would prevent me from using those features.