# Best packages for writing a script for a comedy sketch

Tags: packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are good packages for laying out a play?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/what-are-good-packages-for-laying-out-a-play)

I'm about to start writing some scripts for some comedy sketches and I would like some advice on how to do it best in LaTeX.

The scripts will need to have bits of information like stage directions and dialogue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at the [`dramatist`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dramatist) package.

Some other packages which might help you:

- [`drama`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/drama)
- [`plari`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/plari)
- [`play`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/play)