# How to obtain two columns text as in scripts

Tags: documentclass-writing

I am trying to modify the class `sides` to write scripts (no particular packages), and I was wondering how to obtain the following output for every character:

```
Donald Duck: Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem
             Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
```

In the text the code should look something like `\character{Donald Duck}{Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum...}`but I do not really know what to write in the `.cls` to get this output.

Comment: Consider using lists instead of true two-column mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I took a look at the various options and some look promising, e.g., `\labeling`. However, what should I actually write in the class file to have something that works? I just realized I do not really know how to do it, since everytime I should begin and end an enviroment, and I have no clue on how to do this in the `.cls`file.

Comment: Please post an example how the environmemts should look like.

Comment: You could define a new list environment with, e.g., `enumitem` (let's call it "xyz") and then use `\begin{xyz}\character{bli}{bla blub}\character{quack}{zzz}\end{xyz}` where each `\character` does sth. like `\item[#1] #2`.

Comment: Right! But the problem is how to avoid to write `\begin{xyz}`and `\end{xyz}`everytime. I would like to have it built in so that I can write `\character{bli}{bla blub}` every time avoiding to write begin and end, and this is what I don't know how to do in the class file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good packages for laying out a play?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/what-are-good-packages-for-laying-out-a-play)

Answer (score 1):

For example, something like this:

```
\def\character#1#2{\par
   \setbox0=\hbox{#1:\quad}\dimen0=\wd0
   \hbox{\box0 \vtop{\advance\hsize by-\dimen0 \noindent #2}}
   \medskip
}

\character{Donald Duck}{Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
                        Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum...}

\bye
```